# how to list applications using audio?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I am trying to fastly check if an application audio is working or not (because sometimes sound fails to start. It is application bug/limitation I guess).

What I am doing is to record 1s sample and check if there is something on it. But that is slow here.

I wonder if there is some way to list all applications using pulse audio on ubuntu 12.10?

I believe it has something to do with audio listening ports; other answers pointed to that but none worked here; they only listed the pulseaudio PID, but what I need to know is: **what applications are using pulseaudio?**, and I need to do this in the command line to use with scripts!!

Comment: So you basically need the "Applications" tab from `pavucontrol` but as command line interface to use programmatically?

Comment: yes, something like that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To obtain a list of audio streams **presently** playing to any of available pulseaudio sinks we may issue the following command:

```
pacmd list-sink-inputs
```

This will give us a rather long list of all details for a given stream. Amongst others it will also give us informantion on the application which called pulseaudio in the field `application.name`.

Comment: `application.process.id` from that output works great thx!! I wonder if this output can be more verbose showing what kind of sounds are being played? I would like to detect if music is being played too; I will think, may be this deserve a new specific question, with all I learned packed into :) thx!

Comment: yeah, there is a lot more information on a stream. `media.role` e.g. gives "music" when music is played, `media.name` will even give you information on what music it is (if the player announces this via d-bus MPRIS).

Comment: oh, there is no `media.role` on my pacmd output! versions: "pacmd 2.1, Compiled with libpulse 2.1.0, Linked with libpulse 2.1.0"; I read the stream may not have that property, what seems the case here :(

Comment: That may be possible indeed. You may try with different players but if the source you send to them is incompletely tagged it may fail as well.

Comment: Also, `pacmd list-source-outputs` to see which apps are recording. `pacmd help | grep "list-"` to see all listings available.